# How do I display and calculate average ? And how do I write the value to the text file only once?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(sensor.Value);
if (value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
if (value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;

label8.Text = maxTemp.ToString() + "c";
label8.Visible = true;
label9.Text = minTemp.ToString() + "c";
label9.Visible = true;
temperature_label.Text = sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";
int t = temperature_label.Text.Length;
if (t > 3)
{
   temperature_label.Location = new Point(238, 200);
}
```

label8 display maximum temperature label9 display the minimum and temeprature_label display the current.
I want to add a label that will display in real time the current average. How can i do it ?

And in this part of the code im writing the current temeprature to a logger(text) file if its above a temperature the user set:

```
if (sensor.Value > float.Parse(textbox3_value))
{
     Logger.Write("The current temperature is ===> " + sensor.Value);
     button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

The problem is that all this codes are in a timer tick that is updating every second.
And its writing to the Logger file its adding each time a new line.

The logger file for example look like this:

```
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 71
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 71
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 71
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 71
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 71
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 72
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 72
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 73
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 74
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 73
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 73
```

And i want to make the logger file format to be something like this:

```
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> Session Started
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The current temperature is ===> 71
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The last highest temperature was ===> 80
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The last minimum temperature was ===> 40
1/1/2014--12:50 PM ==> The average temperature is ===> 75
```

And when there is a new value of one of this lines it will update this line value and won't add a new one.

This is the Write method in the Logger class:

```
public static void Write(string str)
{
    if (mut.WaitOne() == false)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(full_path_log_file_name, true))
        {
            sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "--" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " ==> " + str);
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want the log file to just have those five lines (and never anymore) that update as values change. You could do this by overwriting the file each time (change second parameter in the `StreamWriter` constructor to `false`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a list to store all values, and a variable to store average:

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();
double average = 0.0;
```

And in here :

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(sensor.Value);
values.Add(value);
average = values.Average();
Logger.Write("The average temperature is ===> " + average);
```